# Switches for LazyLoading with Repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

By default LazyLoading is disabled in my DbContext. I use repository pattern and in some case I need to get only simple object and in other I need to get object with values of navigations properties.

How can I implement something like switches for LazyLoading?

Any help will be appreciated

I have one solution that works but I'm not sure that it is correct:
in interface of repository I added new property

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        T GetById(object id);
        void Insert(T entity);
        .....
        bool LazyLoadingSwitches { set; }
    }
```

Then implemented it:

```
public bool LazyLoadingSwitches 
{
    set
    {
        this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = value;
    } 
}
```

and when I need to get model with related data then I use in controller:

```
repository.LazyLoadingSwitches = true;
name = order.Customer.FullName; 
repository.LazyLoadingSwitches = false;
```

Please suggest me what is the best solution for that?

Comment: Looks alright to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents:

I think implementing a wrapper around the `this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = value;` call is OK. I would implement it as a method though, a write only property is quite odd.

In my coding I let the code that executes the query decide if it wants to use lazy loading or `.Include` statements. Most important is that the code that is going to consume the class that was returned finds all data in it that is needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use include:

```
order.Include("Customer");
var name = order.Customer.FullName;
```

Sample with lambda expression:

```
order.Include(o => o.Customer);
var name = order.Customer.FullName;
```