# Web API - Return some fields from model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I'm having this model :

```
public class Quiz
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CurrentQuestion { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } 
}
```

There is `[JsonIgnore]` which tells JSON Serializer to ignore this field(Questions). So,I'm having an action which returns serialized Quiz without Questions. I have to implement another action which will return **all** fields (Questions inclusive). How can I do this ? I need both actions.

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to simply copy all the information to another class (with the same variables but no [JsonIgnore] attributes), and then serialize that.

Comment: Why not have 2 classes. Everything but Questions goes into a class called CurrentQuestion, then Quiz has a CurrentQuestion Object and the collection. Then you can have a "GetCurrentQuestion" action, and a "GetQuiz" action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very good practice not to return your domain models from and API. Better way is to create view model classes and return them instead.

So in your example you'd simply create:

```
public class QuizViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CurrentQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

and use it to return data from your API.

Obviously in some bigger classes it would be nightmare to crate the code copying all the properties, but don't worry - Automapper (http://automapper.org/) comes to rescue! :)

```
//Best put this line in app init code
Mapper.CrateMap<Quiz, QuizViewModel>();

//And in your API
var quiz = GetSomeQuiz();
return Mapper.Map<QuizViewModel>(quiz);
```

You then create another view model class with Questions field in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to slightly change your code as below although its very simple :)

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Quiz
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int CurrentQuestion { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class QuizWithQuestions : Quiz
    {
        public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when you want to include Collection of Questions as well use `QuizWithQuestions` class.

Comment: Excellent, but why have you put Quiz as abstract class ?

Comment: Sorry old habbit :P @XavierWOLFF

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. And my solution is:
By default I have DBContext with disable LazyLoading:

```
        public EFDbContext()
            :base("EFDbContext")
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
```

So, all  navigation property (like `Questions`) will be `NULL`. Then in my WebAPIConfig I configure formatter to hide null values:

```
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
                = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling
                 = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

When I need a result with all fields from model then I just turn on the LazyLoading in controller:

```
 repository.SwitchLazyLoading(true);
```

The method in repository:

```
       public void SwitchLazyLoading(bool value)
        {
             this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = value;
        }
```

I do not use `[JsonIgnore]` I use only `[IgnoreDataMember]`
Please look at the [Switches for LazyLoading with Repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771136/switches-for-lazyloading-with-repository-pattern)